# How to lay one video over another

Tags: software-rec, video-editing

I have two video clips. What I need is for the first video clip to play behind the second. I need to be able to choose the offset since the two videos are not exactly in sync.I need to adjust the position of the second clip on the first. (It should be at different places at different times).What would be the right software to do this. Also are there any blog posts about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible through **IMOVIE** tool..but it can't run on windows platform,for more information on how to lay one video on another tool view this video

[laying one video  on another using imovie tool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYqu0EeWC0w)

its also possible through **sony vegas** for windows,for more help refer this link

[how to overlay video using sony vegas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AppzM0DIpzM)

[for more overlaying tricks and help regarding video editing](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/304068-Overlay-Video-on-another-Video)

[for overlaying video](http://forum.cyberlink.com/forum/posts/list/18090.page;jsessionid=4B65F4D6826DF391FCCAB8AFD80DB45E#92754)

i update my post with the freeware links as sonyvegas and adobe are costs..some of the users maybe comfortable with freewares for them  :

[link to download freeware video editing tools which are more powerfull](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/video-editing-30-free-tools-and-web-services-to-get-things-done/)

Comment: I need it to run on either windows or linux. I dont have a mac available. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ i added the link pls refer it for more reference

Comment: Sony Vegas is almost 599 dollars:). Any ideas how we can do this using movie maker

Comment: @sab ill update soon

Comment: Sure no issue. Your answers are definitely worth the wait!

Comment: @sab i updated my post

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Premiere Elements 10](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere-elements.html) can do this.

I've not used it for many years (8+, and an older version at that) but I remember it being very easy even then.